# The previous page link appears in address bar in MVC3 Razor application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using MVC3/Razor. After I login into the website, it appears the home page, but I don't understand why the previous page url appears.

Scenario: When I redirect user from LogOn page to Home page the url in the address bar appears like "http://localhost:55104/Account/LogOn" instead of "http://localhost:55104/Home/Index"

Account Controller

```
 // GET: /Account/LogOn
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    // POST: /Account/LogOn
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (AppAuthentication.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password, "10.0.3.18"))
                {
                    string userName = model.UserName;
                    var user = new List<String>();
                    MySqlConnection con = DAL.GetMySqlConnection();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT user_id, user_fname FROM users  WHERE  user_code='" + userName + "' AND user_treeCode <> 'xxx'", con);
                    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        user.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
                        user.Add(rdr.GetString(1));
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user[0], model.RememberMe);
                    Session["userID"] = user[0];
                    Session["userName"] = user[1];
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.OpenID = "Invalid credentials ";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Gloabal.asax

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );           
    }

 protected void Application_Start()
    {                       
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Comment: It could be routing related - could you post your route configuration?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The post is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your login form must be an Ajax form.  In that case, RedirectToAction acts like a View method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            returnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "App");
        }
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

And in the view:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "LogOn", 
    null, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        OnSuccess = "success" 
    }, 
    new { 
        id = "SignInForm", ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] 
    })) { %>
        <<Page HTML Controls>>
        <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript">
function success(context) {
    var returnUrl = context.get_data().returnUrl;
    if (returnUrl) {
        window.location.href = returnUrl;
    } else {
        // TODO: update the target form element with the returned partial html
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try to use use your solution.

Comment: I tried to use your advice, but I have already in the adress bar `http://localhost:1413/Account/LogOn` and it displays in the page a mesage 'undefined'. Then, if I make F5, I am redirected to Home/Index